# calling method in python to increase the age of the animal

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods

I have been assigned to create a dog named `'Molly'` of age `1`. I call the method `grow` to increase the age by `2` and print it.

I know how to make Molly run, but I am confused on how to increase her age, it keeps on showing `None`.

Any help will work, but it would be best if it could be explained. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
class Dog():
    """ a class representing a dog """

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        """ Initialize name and age attributes. """
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def run(self):
        """ Simulate a dog running. """
        print(self.name.title() + " is running ...")

    def grow(self, year):
        """ Update age by adding year. """
        self.age += year

molly = Dog("Molly", 1)

print(molly.name + " is " + str(molly.grow(2)))
molly.run()
```

The output of this is

```
Molly is None
Molly is running ...
```

Comment: The way you are using `print` suggests Python 3, yet you tagges python-2.7. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grow` method is not returning the `age` attribute, it is just setting the `age` attribute.

`grow` returns `None` (implicitly) and that's what you see in your `print` call.

Use

```
print(molly.age) # 1
molly.grow(2) # adjust age
print(molly.age) # 3
```

to see what I mean.

You can rewrite your original attempt as

```
molly.grow(2)
print(molly.name + " is " + str(molly.age)) # Molly is 3
```

or a little more eleganlty with string formatting as

```
molly.grow(2)
print('{0.name} is {0.age}'.format(molly)) # Molly is 3
```